# High cost of geometry bitmap heap scan

Tags: postgis, geometry, spatial-index

I have a PostGIS database with tables osm_admin (with contains all administrative boundaries from osm data) and osm_landusages (with contains all landuse areas form osm - like forests, industrial/residential areas etc, 35kk rows total)

In the query below I want to find all landusages that has bounding box intersecting with one of London's district.

```sql
with london as (SELECT * 
                 FROM osm_admin 
                WHERE osm_id = -184710)
SELECT ol.*
  FROM osm_landusages ol,
       london l
 WHERE l.geometry && ol.geometry
```

Query works fine, but it takes 50 seconds to complete.

Here is the explain analyze result

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=140.25..13930.01 rows=35341 width=543) (actual time=2067.725..49146.068 rows=4585 loops=1)"
"  CTE london"
"    ->  Index Scan using osm_admin_osm_id_idx on osm_admin  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=7480) (actual time=0.028..0.032 rows=1 loops=1)"
"          Index Cond: (osm_id = '-51827'::integer)"
"  ->  CTE Scan on london l  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.032..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on osm_landusages ol  (cost=131.81..13886.21 rows=3534 width=543) (actual time=2067.686..49136.460 rows=4585 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: (l.geometry && geometry)"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=2247"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on osm_landusages_geom  (cost=0.00..130.92 rows=3534 width=0) (actual time=2046.779..2046.779 rows=4585 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (l.geometry && geometry)"
"Planning time: 0.584 ms"
"Execution time: 49148.356 ms"
```

The Bitmap Index Scan looks fine, with cost of 130, and then there is Bitmap Heap Scan that has the same condidtion, and is increasing cost to 13886. Is there anything I can do with it?

I increased work_mem to 256MB, but it didn't change anything, also I ran cluster on the osm_landusages geometry index, and it still not finished, after 4 days.

Comment: The bitmap heap scan actually reads the rows, while the bitmap index scan reads the index only. Have your run a `vaccum, analyze` on this table? You have 3534 rows stored in 2247 blocks (pages), so 1 or 2 record per block, which is small. Either the rows are really big, or the blocks are full of dead space which would be reclaimed by a vaccum. Do you really have 543 columns? You will likely get much better performance if the rows had less columns (like 2 columns only, ID + land_use)

Comment: @JGH table has only 7 columns so it shouldn't be the problem. I think I was using vacuum analyze, but I will try again and check if it helps.

Comment: ah yes, sorry, 543 bytes, not cols...

Comment: well, looks like vacuum helped a bit, because query is running 4-5 time faster now, but explain shows same values, so I dont know if it cleaned these blocks and dead spaces properly

Comment: gotta run `VACUUM FULL` to fully clear dead space and reallocate to free disk space, then recluster the table. if it further increases performance, I doubt it. maybe select the london geometry in a right hand side subquery to the `&&` operator instead of in a CTE.